# Emploi métaphorique du mot "parapluie"

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, usage

> So continuum mechanics is not a new or challenging topic. Rather it is a chance to start over and put all that was studied previously under a single *umbrella*.

Peut-on employer le mot *parapluie* dans ce sens métaphorique ? Est-il un anglicisme ? Je me demande voyant les traductions de Deepl (traduit par toit) et Google Translate (pas de traduction).
Pour plus de précision, voici les traductions de Deepl et Google respectivement (je les ai modifiées légèrement) :

> La mécanique des milieux continus n'est donc pas un sujet nouveau ou stimulant. C'est plutôt l'occasion de repartir à zéro et de regrouper tout ce qui a déjà été étudié sous un même toit.
>
> La mécanique des milieux continus n’est donc pas un sujet nouveau ou difficile. C'est plutôt une chance de recommencer et de regrouper tout ce qui a été étudié précédemment.

Comment: On a bien "parapluie" dans ce sens-là, notamment "terme parapluie" ou "[Espèce parapluie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A8ce_parapluie)' mais ça ne fonctionne pas bien dans ta phrase. Je pense que ta deuxième option est la meilleure.

Comment: Pour moi c'est « repartir de zéro », suis-je puriste dans ce cas ? Je suis sûre que ça a été déjà discuté sur FL.

Comment: ÉTIQUETTE! Sous une même étiquette.

Comment: @Laure, même si je comprends les 2 expressions dans le même sens, je pense que vous avez raison. "Repartir à" implique que l'on va parler de la destination, "Repartir de" va être suivi du point de départ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'emploi métaphorique du mot parapluie existe en français mais en général en conservant l'idée de protection, le premier exemple qui me vient en tête étant le parapluie nucléaire.

Dans l'emploi métaphorique anglais utilisé dans la question<sup>1</sup> on commence à le trouver dans le cas d'« organisations parapluie » qui est désormais sorti des dictionnaires bilingues pour être de plus en plus employé dans la presse. C'est un anglicisme au départ.
Peut-être l'usage du mot continuera-t-il à évoluer mais pour l'instant je ne l'emploierais pas pour parler d'une réunion d'items de même nature.

> sous un même toit

ne me plait pas ici. Mais ça se comprend.

> regrouper tout ce qui a été étudié précédemment

pourquoi pas...

J'ai pensé à « sous un même chapeau » mais ça ne me semble pas vraiment mieux que « toit ».

À envisager :

- ce qui a déjà été étudié sous une même dénomination
- sous une même rubrique
- dans un même cadre

mais je suppose qu'un scientifique pourrait faire mieux.

---

<sup>1</sup> qui correspond à la définition donnée dans le *Cambridge online* (something that includes or represents a group or range of similar things)

Comment: "sous un même dénominateur" ne devrait-il pas plutôt être "sous une même dénomination"? En effet je pense que le seul emploi valable de "dénominateur" soit dans le cadre mathématique d'une division ou éventuellement dans une expression imagée faisant cependant référence à cet usage mathématique. Soit dit en passant, "sous une même dénomination" me paraît moi aussi bien plus approprié dans le cas précis que "sous un même toit", que j'interprète toujours avec le sens beaucoup plus littéral de "dans le même bâtiment"

Comment: @LaurentS. Tu as raison - dénomination mauvais suffixe.

Answer (score 3):

En plus des réponses déjà données, je proposerais :

> ...regrouper tout ce qui a déjà été étudié sous un même **terme**.

Cela dit, je trouve la phrase encore meilleure avec une inversion afin de rapprocher le verbe "regrouper" de son complément direct :

> ... regrouper *sous un même terme/sous une même dénomination/etc* tout ce qui a déjà été étudié.

Comment: Il me semble qu'il n'est pas question de linguistique mais seulement de philosophie de la physique, la mécanique des milieux continus n'étant pas vu donc sous l'aspect d'un terme mais sous celui d'un ensemble de principes unificateurs.

Comment: Ah c'est possible, peut-être ai-je alors mal compris la proposition initiale

Answer (score 1):

Il existe une terme traditionnel qui semble convenir très bien : « égide ».

- La mécanique des milieux continus n'est donc pas un sujet nouveau ou stimulant. C'est plutôt l'occasion de repartir à zéro et de regrouper tout ce qui a déjà été étudié sous une seule égide.

Complément

Peut être plus exact serait la notion de « thème unificateur », terme qui émane des apports de user **Laurent S.**.

- La mécanique des milieux continus n'est donc pas un sujet nouveau ou stimulant. C'est plutôt l'occasion de repartir à zéro et de regrouper tout ce qui a déjà été étudié sous un thème unificateur.

Comment: Selon moi le terme "égide" implique une protection, d'ailleurs à l'origine cela désigne un bouclier, je n'aurais donc pas spontanément employé ce terme qui est de plus assez formel. Cependant, il faut bien avouer que "umbrella/parapluie" a aussi un sens de protection qui n'est pas vraiment utilisé dans l'expression anglaise non plus, alors pourquoi pas...

Comment: Étant grec (le mot est d'origine grec) je suis content de voir une telle réponse:-)!

Comment: @LaurentS. Le TLFi ajoute une notion de sauvegarde ( Garantie, protection accordée, assurée par une autorité, une institution.), mais on ne s'éloigne pas trop de cette idée de protection ; il manquerait une nuance et vous me la suggérez.

Comment: Sous l'égide de = sous la protection de (unanimité de tous les  dictionnaires consultés), l'employer dans la phrase du PO ne serait non pas dans le sens « traditionnel » du terme mais une création. Mais il faut que la langue évolue, faisons la bouger, c'est bien. @LaurentS. L'emploi de *umbrella* dans la phrase de Dimitris n'a pas conservé l'idée de protection. « Égide » par contre introduit une notion de domination-dominé que n'a pas l'emploi de *umbrella* ici.

Comment: @Laure Je suis bien d'accord pour de l'évolution, mais pas pour un déplacement des notions établies, pas pour établir des proximités propres à introduire l'incertitude, à rendre difficile l'identification des concepts. Je sais bien qu'une bonne partie des langues européennes sont construites à partir de ce principe d'empilement de concepts sur un même mot (à n'en plus finir pour des mots comme « à » et « de » en français), mais je crois plus utile de faire cela le moins possible (à moins que l'on puisse prouver que la « parenté » que l'on établit par ces empilements. (champ 1/3)

Comment: @Laure à un effet qui compense). On trouve aussi dans le dictionnaire de l'Ac. « sous le patronage de », ce qui n'implique aucune notion de protection (surprise), mais des notions tutelle, de guidance, de prise en charge [Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/égide?page=1);  les principes de la mécanique en milieux continus sont des principes régisseurs des phénomènes de déformation et d'écoulement; (champ 2/3)

Comment: @Laure « sous le parapluie » de ces principes signifie « tels qu'expliqués et contrôlés par ces principes » et « sous le patronage de la mécanique en milieux continus » n'est pas si mauvais, excepté que pour des inanimés je ne vois pas comment on peut utiliser « patronage » ; mais on doit pouvoir prendre cela comme « sous l'égide des lois » : il est clair que si les lois protègent tout aussi bien elles contraignent, elles soumettent, d'où un patronage (figurativement). (champ 3/3)

Answer (score 1):

> La mécanique des milieux continus n'est pas un sujet nouveau. C'est plutôt l'occasion de reprendre les études précédentes.